# How to create a new column of conditional count in a Pandas' DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby, data-manipulation

I have a DataFrame, `df`, like:

```
id   date
a    2019-07-11
a    2019-07-16
b    2018-04-01 
c    2019-08-10
c    2019-07-11
c    2018-05-15
```

I want to add a count column and shows how many rows with the same id exist in the date with a date that is before the date of that row. Meaning:

```
id   date        count
a    2019-07-11  0
a    2019-07-16  1
b    2018-04-01  0 
c    2019-08-10  2
c    2019-07-11  1
c    2018-05-15  0
```

If you believe it is easier in SQL and know how to do it, that works for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
In [1688]: df.sort_values('date').groupby('id').cumcount()                                                                                                                                                  
Out[1688]: 
2    0
5    0
0    0
4    1
1    1
3    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Do I need to sort it by ```date``` first?

Comment: Ok, I got what you are saying. Gimme a minute.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! Can you also show how we can add additional filters/conditions? For example, a new column ```count_month``` that shows how many rows with the same id and smaller date exist in ```df``` that the date is not older than a month before the date for that row?